# Непонятное поведение выбранных элементов JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

У меня есть простая верстка блока источника:

```
<span>
    <input type="hidden" name="first" class="cool-class" val="myValue" />
    <input type="hidden" name="second" class="fine-class" val="myValue2" />
</span>
```

и есть верстка блока назначения:

```
<form>
    <div id="_destination"></div>
    <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

и есть следующий скрипт, который выбирает все элементы `<input>` из источника и добавляет в блок назначения посредством элемента `checkbox`

```
<input type="checkbox" id="_my_check" />

$(document)
        .on('change', "#_my_check", function () {
         var cool = $(".cool-class");
         var fine = $(".fine-class");

         $("#_destination").append(cool);
         $("#_destination").append(fine);
}
```

Так вот, при выполнении данного скрипта, элементы удаляюся из блока источника, а мне необходимо чтоб они оставались. Помогите советом.

Comment: А много у вас в коде таких элементов input с id="_my_check"?

Comment: @Quazimorda такой елемент всего  1. А вот блоков исочника может быть много.

Comment: Тогда всё хорошо. Тут уже встречалось на сайте, что или спросивший, или отвечавшие добавляли несколько элементом с одним и тем же id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
     $("#_destination").find(".cool-class").remove();
     $("#_destination").find(".fine-class").remove();

     $("#_destination").append(cool.clone());
     $("#_destination").append(fine.clone());
```